# Move any character from one of the string to the end, find at least how many moves you can make so that two strings become the same string

Tags: algorithm

I am doing some coding practice today and I encountered this question which I couldn't find an approach to solve this question, can anyone share their insight about this problem?

---

---

**You are given two strings S and T, you can move any character(any position) in S to the end, find at least how many moves you can make so that S and T become the same string.**

You can assume S, T are in the same length with same characters.

> Example:
>   S: cadb
>   T: abcd
>   Output:
>   2

Explanation:
1. Move 'c' to the end first then S became "adbc"
 2. Move 'd' to the end then S became "abcd" which is same as T.

---

---

Maybe DFS or BFS would help? I don't know...

I came up with a very naive and rough idea when I saw this question for the first time which is move every characters that are not in the same position then check, if the new string is not same then move again, until they become the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're done, the characters you *don't* move will come before all the character you *do* move, and they will match a prefix of the target string.

To move the minimum number of characters, find the longest subsequence of S that is a prefix of T.  Then move all the other ones in the right order to match the rest of T.  If you can't then there is no match possible.

Easy to do -- you just find characters from T in S in order:

```
T:  lookingForThis
S:  ThiloFokrinsgo
       ^^ ^^ ^^ ^ 
Keep: looking
Move:        ForThis
```